# Passport.js, jwt, local and facebook via websockets only

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, passport.js

I'm trying to understand how I can use socketio together with passport to:

1. Sign up
2. Sign in
3. Restrict specific routes on the websocket to privileged users while public routes do not require this.
4. Utilize JWT's via the authorization header and keep things stateless, this means no session storage in the server

I understand the following.

I create a Strategy:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: 'x',
  clientSecret: 'x',
  callbackURL: '/auth/facebook/callback',
  profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'emails'],
  session: false,
}, async (token, tokenSecret, profile, done) => {
  // find or create new user here and return
  done(null, user);
}));

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  session: false,
}, async (email, password, done) => {
  // find or create new user here and return
  done(null, user);
}));
```

How does one use this in the incoming socket on the server?

#### server code:

```
.on('sign-in', (data) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
    //do stuff?
  })(req, res, next);
  socket.emit('sign-in', response); // <-- back to the client
})
.on('public-route', (data) => {
  // all websocket clients should be able to access this
})
.on('private-route', (data) => {
  // only authenticated websocket clients should access this
})
```

I don't understand how it can be used with websockets. Here is how my thoughts are regarding the flow.

1. Client connects to the server via websockets
2. The server saves the socket connection in a unauthenticated users array since there is no JWT sent (The client can access public websocket routes)
3. The client clicks sign in via facebook.
4. Websocket sends an emit to the server with credentials
5. Server picks up the emit with credentials
6. ...what happens here for the websocket to utilize passport?
7. A) Server does an emit with a JWT if successful sign in
8. B) Server does an emit with a message if not successful. END
9. If successful server saves socket in separate array for authenticated users (the client can access private routes now)
10. ...How should those routes look like with passport? How does passport protect those routes?
11. client saves the jwt in cookie, if the user decides to shut the browser and reopen it for persistent sign in.

That's kinda the image in my head. I just don't see where passport.js fits in anywhere. I also don't really have a good idea of how to handle the authenticated and unauthenticated websockets apart from two arrays.

I'm very close to just implementing my own authentication/authorization but I'd prefer to use a tried and tested method hence passport.js.

I hope this question makes sense, tell if it doesn't and I'll refactor!